# adding php variable into Xpath

Tags: php, xpath

i just need to add in a variable into the xpath my code is as followed

```
$target = $xml->xpath('//gig[@id=$1]');
```

but I need it too but something like

```
$target = $xml->xpath("//gig[@id=$" $change . "]");
```

Is this possible ?

If so could some one help ?

Comment: What is the question? You provided (except for the missing . typo) the solution yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
$target = $xml->xpath("//gig[@id=$". $change . "]");
```

or, if you do not need the $ sign

```
$target = $xml->xpath("//gig[@id=". $change . "]");
```

If you need to escape a character like " in php use

```
\"
```

Comment: `$target = $xml->xpath("//gig[@id='{$change}']")` is also valid.

Comment: Note that unless the content of `$change` is known, the above code is prone to injections. An attacker can cause arbitrary nodes to be returned (`$change = "some_nonsensical_id'] | a malicious xpath | //some_nonsensical_element_name[@some_nonsensical_attribute_name='"`).

Comment: @Witiko Isn't that the same for the premise in general, interpolating a variable in a string? It is a genuine question I don't claim to know

Comment: Not every string is an SQL command. If you are constructing a string containing natural language text, you may not care too much.