# Using a php variable in an xpath query

Tags: php, variables, xpath

I want to use a php variable in an xpath statement. There is a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109161/adding-php-variable-into-xpath) whose answer does not resolve my problem.

Here is example code (neither $r1 or $r2 create the intended array)

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("menu.xml");
$term = "one";
$r1 = $xml->xpath("//category[@name=$term]");
$r2 = $xml->xpath("//category[@name=" . $term . "]");
$r3 = $xml->xpath("//category[@name='one']");

echo ('$r1 = '); print_r($r1);
echo ('<br>$r2 = '); print_r($r2);
echo ('<br>$r3 = '); print_r($r3);
?>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<menu>
<category name="one">
    <item>Tomato and Cheese</item>
    <item>Onions</item>
    <item>Broccoli</item>
</category>
<category name="two">
    <item>Burger and Fries</item>
    <item>Chicken Sandwich</item>
</category>
<category name="three">
    <item>Filet of Fish</item>
    <item>Exotic Meat Stew</item>   
</category>
```

Output

```
$r1 = Array ( )
$r2 = Array ( ) 
$r3 = Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => one ) [item] => Array ( [0] => Tomato and Cheese [1] => Onions [2] => Broccoli ) ) )
```

I'm probably missing something really simple but am stuck!

Answer (score 4):

You should add single quotes around the variables

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$term = "one";
$r1 = $xml->xpath("//category[@name='$term']");
$r2 = $xml->xpath("//category[@name='" . $term . "']");
$r3 = $xml->xpath("//category[@name='one']");

echo ('$r1 = '); print_r($r1);
echo ('<br>$r2 = '); print_r($r2);
echo ('<br>$r3 = '); print_r($r3);
```

Outputs

```
$r1 = Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => one ) [item] => Array ( [0] => Tomato and Cheese [1] => Onions [2] => Broccoli ) ) )
$r2 = Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => one ) [item] => Array ( [0] => Tomato and Cheese [1] => Onions [2] => Broccoli ) ) )
$r3 = Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => one ) [item] => Array ( [0] => Tomato and Cheese [1] => Onions [2] => Broccoli ) ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Been a while since I've used xpath syntax, however, by deduction, it looks like the only diferrences the single quotes:

The follow are *now* equivalent.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("menu.xml");
$term = "one";
$r1 = $xml->xpath("//category[@name='$term']");
$r2 = $xml->xpath("//category[@name='" . $term . "']");
$r3 = $xml->xpath("//category[@name='one']");
```